# Stack level too deep when using session.first[1] in interpolation paperclip upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, interpolation

I have a model to file upload and interpolation for dynamic path, I want to upload files in session folders created under public directory for each user session

```
Paperclip.interpolates :folder do |attachment, style|
  return session.first[1]
end
```

its giving "stack level too deep" error on upload but it working if I return other values through interpolation

Comment: `Stack Level Too Deep` basically means you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are correctly using interpolations. Interpolations are used to allow paths and URLs to be dynamic. The code from the paperclip guide documents:

```
Paperclip::interpolates :size_of_file do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.upload_file_size
end
```

So, you're not doing anything with the attachment and furthermore the attachment is not tied to the session in any way.